# Styling CurrentValues in Stylesheet

Tags: stylesheet, style, printing

I've succeeded in putting the notebook title into page headers (thanks to @Kuba), but I failed at styling the label.

```
Cell[StyleData["Notebook", "Printout"], PageHeaders->{{
  Cell[TextData[{"", CounterBox["Page"], "/", CounterBox["LastPage"]}], "PageNumber"], 
  None, 
  CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "Title"}] 
  }, 
  {None, None, None }} 
]
```

Simply moving the `CurrentValue` to `Cell` or `TextData` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to do this directly in TaggingRules:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "Title"}] = Cell[
 "test title", FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], FontSize -> 40
]
```

[image]

I managed to make it via stylesheet with

```
Cell[BoxData[DynamicBox[FrontEnd`CurrentValue[...]]], style...]
```

but that also resulted in a crush from time to time so I'd go with the former method.